# Two resources and a debug error when I try to run android project

Tags: android, gradle

Previously these configs were working fine, but from last day getting error mentioned below.
Any idea what's what's wrong with it.

```
[ROOT_PATH]/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml
    Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
    Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    Information:BUILD FAILED
    Information:Total time: 3.962 secs
    Information:3 errors
    Information:0 warnings
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXXXXXXXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    }
```

Comment: try to change buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

Comment: @Drim, Tried but no luck. '23.0.2' is producing same error.

Answer (score 0):

Use recent `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion`. For example, 25 instead of 23.

You'll also probably need to change support library versions to more recent here

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

For example 25.0.1 or newer instead of 23.1.1.

Comment: 25.0.2 worked for me but it's changing style related things. Like EditText error style got changed in TextInputLayout after updating. Need to show EditText validation errors under EditText but after upgrading to 25.0.5 EditText Errors are giving floating error tooltip kind of appearance.